# How to retrieve all rows from a grid along with it's content using cypress

Tags: grid, cypress

cy.get('.grid-content-container').find('.grid-row').its('length').should('be.visible')

is giving the correct length but not sure how to get the records from 'grid-content' in each row?

this is the html:

[dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whwwz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cy.each](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) for looping through the items.

```js
cy.get('.grid-content-container').find('.grid-row').each(gridRow => {
  cy.wrap(gridRow).find('.grid-content').each((gridContent) => {
    // do something with gridContent
  })
})
```